# Error: The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.

Tags: iis-7.5

IIS 7.5, Framework v4.0
Error: The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.
Solutions Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to create web.sitemap file for your site.

This is from MSDN:

> The simplest way to create a site map is to create an XML file named Web.sitemap that organizes the
>   pages in the site hierarchically. This site map is automatically picked up by the default site-map
>   provider for ASP.NET.
>
> The Web.sitemap file must be located in the application root directory, though it can reference other
>   site-map providers, or other site-map files in other directories as long as those files are in the same
>   application.

For more information you may check this article: [ASP.NET Site Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx)